# How to add text to span control dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

net c#. I am using a place holder, and adding span dynamically to the place holder. How can i add text to span dynamically in c# asp.net?

Answer (score 5):

you can use html generic control it would be somethink like this

```
var yourspan = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
span.InnerHtml = "the text inside your span ";
yourspan.Attributes["id"] = "yourspan";
pannel.Controls.Add(span);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**Make Table runat="server"**

```
 <table id="myTable" runat="server" width="100%">    
    <tr>
    <td>
    <span></span>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    **In code behind u do like this** 
 myTable.Rows[1].Cells[0].InnerHtml = "<span id="1">" + YOURTEXT+ "</span>";
```

Comment: @nikhil Is it possible to add css dynamically in asp.net c# . for ex .ao-annotations span:nth-child(3):after,
.ao-annotations span:nth-child(4):after,
.ao-item:nth-child(2) .ao-annotations span:nth-child(1):after {
 left: auto;
 right: 100%;
 margin: -16px -16px 0 0;
 background-image: url(../images/arrow_left.png);
}

Comment: ADD LIKE THIS  myTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Attributes.Add("Class", "YourClassName");

Comment: No . actually i want to add css class like above to .css file . is it possible?

Comment: SO THAT U HAVE ADD ATTRIBUTES TO 1 BY 1

Comment: myTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Style.Add("color", "green");
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Style.Add("background", "green");

Comment: loop tabel and according to that add syles